# Regex for matching data between parenthesis BUT with a pattern to match inside

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, parentheses

I saw many examples of how to get data between parenthesis with regex for python but none with some pattern inside.

For example, I have this data:

```
Overall (each): 37 1/4 × 74 1/2 × 7 7/8 in. (94.6 × 189.2 × 20 dm)
Each, 30 x 50 in. (76.2 x 127 dm.)
24 3/8 x 14 5/8 x 5 1/8 in. (61.9 x 37.1 x 13 dm)
```

What I am tryng to achieve at least is:

```
(94.6 × 189.2 × 20 dm)
(76.2 x 127 dm.)
(61.9 x 37.1 x 13 dm)
```

And the perfect result would be what is below but I am sure this will require a second split:

```
94.6, 189.2, 20 
76.2, 127
61.9, 37.1, 13
```

Currently, I am trying this code: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZeN7hq/1), but as you can see without the success in capturing just the cm parenthesis data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\(([^()]*\bcm\b[^()]*)\)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/rbQgu6/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cm                       'cm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

Comment: Would you recommend any book for a better explanation of this code above?

Comment: @Mensch The https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an amazing resource.